# C# serialization issue while moving to dot net framework 4.5 from 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protobuf-net, dotfuscator

My software currently works at framework 3.5. I need to move on framework 4.5 with current settings. But version of `Dotfuscator` which is in 3.5 is not supported in 4.5 and I do not want to buy(due to cost issues) the updated version of 'Dotfuscator'.

So what I thought that I will use `Protobuf-net` serialization to save my settings. And after moving to framework 4.5 I will introduce a new obfuscator.

But protobuf-net does not support non generic sarialization. I have many Hashtables and ArrayList. Is there any way to implement this? Or is there any other kind of serialization which can solve my issue?

> I can't use binary serialization or xml serialization, because it will
>   use the current obfuscated(dotfuscator) serialization which I want to
>   bypass.

```
    [ProtoContract]
    public class MyClass
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int id;
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public OtherClass otherClass; //It may also have non generics
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public Hashtable someHashTable; //Protobuf-net doesn't supports.
        [ProtoMember(4)]
        public ArrayList someArrayList; //Protobuf-net doesn't supports this too.
   }
```

Comment: do you have some example of what you are trying to serialize and the expected output? question does not address if this is JSON, XML, etc?

Comment: I have objects of classes which may have generic and non generic both kind of data types.

Comment: If you don't mind how it's serialized, could you serialize to JSON with something like Newtonsoft.Json. It handles pretty much anything I throw at it. Or do you have some specific output requirements for the serialization. You mention obfuscation however I feel like this is a separate layer to the serialization.

Comment: @Joe_DM okay. let me look into JSON.

Comment: I see you added a sample class that you're trying to serialize. Could there be an issue deserializing it if they are private scopes fields? It's off topic so no need to reply, but something to keep in mind if you start having issues deserializing back into the object

Comment: Why not build a class project with Dotfuscator code in class with Net 3.5.  Then add class to main project which is built with Net 4.5

Comment: Actually protobuf-net works fine with non-generic code as long as it is homogeneous. What are the things you are *storing* in this hashtable / arraylist? Are they always the same things?

Comment: @Joe_DM - JSON does the job but takes a lot of time in serialization/deserialization. And the file size also higher comparitevely.

Comment: @MarcGravell Converting ArrayLists into Generic lists and Hashtables into Dictionaries helped me to use Protobuf-net. Which is quite faster (almost equal to binary serialization, even faster) and also less file size. So thats solves my problem for now.